# Is there a way to change the default delimiter of hive query

Tags: hive, header, hiveql, delimiter

We access hive via putty, results will displayed with columns being separated by space(\001)

If data is null and number of columns in table in huge, then its tough to figure out which columns are null.

Is there a hive property to change the delimiter to some other character.

Currently i am using concat function to add delimiter, but wanted to know if there is easy way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

CTAS (Create table as select) and Insert Select statement can write files to your system with the different delimiter if specified with `FIELED TERMINATED` BY property.

```
insert overwrite local directory './test' 
row format delimited 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
select * from src ;
```

If you want to perform this operation on Hive CLI and writing data to file there then you can use `sed`. ex.

```
hive -e 'select * from my_table' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > output.txt
```

Hive had JIRA issue for the same which is closed now but description has good useful information.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3682

Here's the useful resource link from documentation:
[Writing data to File](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries)

Comment: Thanks, But my question was different, this will help when we copy data set to files, and i am doing this right now when we want to export data from table.

Comment: We use putty to access hive, If we query a table we get columns separated by space, Is there any hive property or alternative which we can try to change this to some other dellmiter